# Bundling and Minification dynamically

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a question about bundling. Think about a situation like this. Take jquery DataTables for example. It has few plugins that you can use as and when you need them. In some pages, just using the base script files will do the job. but in another page, I might need to use Fixed Header plugin, in another page I might need to use Fixed Header plugin as well as Table Tools plugin.

What is the best way to approach these kind of situations in bundling. Should I create just one bundle which include all of the script files (even the ones that I might not use in some pages but in others) or create bundles specifically to each page or is there a better way of doing this. I'd like to be able to do something like

`Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datatables", "FixedHeader", "TableTools")`
which will include the relevant files and minify them.

Any help really appreciated.

Thanks,
Amila

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of this, no one can answer for you. Bundling is always a trade-off: you're reducing requests at the cost of a larger file that has to be downloaded. You'll personally have to weigh the additional weight added by those scripts in the initial request versus the time it will take to request them later.

As a general guideline, this will mostly be about your audience. Do you expect a high number of mobile users? At least in the U.S., mobile data is expensive and fairly limited (because of the outrageous cost, people try to choose the lowest data tiers possible). Forcing your mobile users to download a large JS file which includes code that may never be run, is a waste of their data. While, if your target will be desktop users, a big file is no problem and is in fact preferable, as there's no concerns typically over data usage and the page load times for other pages will be improved. Even with mobile, though, sometimes users prefer faster page loads over less data usage, so even that has to be judged.

That said, if you don't choose to bundle them all together from the start, you *can* actually create bundles on the fly.

```
@{ BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/onthefly").Include("~/Path/To/Some/Script.js")); }
```

And then, as usual:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/onthefly")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, mobile users of the site is very less. But even with desktops, there might be users with low internet speed. That's who I want to address. I'll try the code you have provided. Thanks again

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look at the [Enfold project](https://github.com/achingono/Enfold). It might be able to accomplish what you need.

Assuming you have the following views in the web project:

> ~/Views/Home/About.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Home/Contact.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml

You can organize your Javascript files this way:

> ~/Scripts/Views/default.js
>   ~/Scripts/Views/Home/default.js
>   ~/Scripts/Views/Home/about.js
>   ~/Scripts/Views/Home/contact.js
>   ~/Scripts/Views/Home/index.js

With such a setup, the following bundles will be created:

> **~/bundles/home/about**
>
> > ~/scripts/views/default.js
> >     ~/scripts/views/home/default.js
> >     ~/scripts/views/home/about.js
>
> **~/bundles/home/contact**
>
> > ~/scripts/views/default.js
> >     ~/scripts/views/home/default.js
> >     ~/scripts/views/home/contact.js
>
> **~/bundles/home/index**
>
> > ~/scripts/views/default.js
> >     ~/scripts/views/home/default.js
> >     ~/scripts/views/home/index.js

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Fixed, does that help?